# change opacity of div based on value of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby

I have a credit card input and a set of icons (master card, visa, discover, american express).

When I type in a valid master card number in the credit card input I want the master card icon's opacity to be 1. Same goes for the rest of the icons and valid credit card numbers.

html:

```
<div class="payment-cc-type">
  <div class="payment-cc-icon">
  <div id="american_express" class="cc-opacity"></div>
  <div id="visa" class="cc-opacity"></div>
  <div id="master_card" class="cc-opacity"></div>
  <div id="discover" class="cc-opacity"></div>
  </div>
  <%= f.text_field :cc_type %>
</div>
<div class="payment-cc-number">
  <%= f.label :cc_number, 'Number' %>
  <%= f.text_field :cc_number %>
</div>
```

js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#payment_cc_number").change(function(){
    $('.cc-opacity').val(getCreditCardType($(this).val())).css('opacity', 1);

});
});

function getCreditCardType(accountNumber)
{

//start without knowing the credit card type
var result = "unknown";

//first check for MasterCard
if (/^5[1-5]/.test(accountNumber))
{
    result = "MasterCard";
}

//then check for Visa
else if (/^4/.test(accountNumber))
{
    result = "Visa";
}

//then check for AmEx
else if (/^3[47]/.test(accountNumber))
{
    result = "American Express";
}
//then check for Discover
else if (/^6011/.test(accountNumber))
{
    result = "Discover";
}

return result;
}
```

with this code all the icons turn their opacity to 1, not the specific one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#payment_cc_number").change(function(){
    //Get Card
    var card = getCreditCardType($(this).val());
    $('.cc-opacity').val(card);

    //As you have defined ids as visa etc
    card = card.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '_')
    $('#'+card).css('opacity', 1);
});
```

Comment: @anmaree, I have updated answer. '#'+card is selector for you div

Comment: it still doesn't seem to be working, is the # suppose to be replaced with a name of a div id? I am using classes

Comment: @anmaree, You have define ids and # is id selector. can you post value of card. just alert what are you getting